# Return value of showmodaldialog with HTTP URL to HTTPS page

Tags: javascript, html, http, redirect, https

Recently we enabled SSL in one of our projects which still maintains compatibility for Internet Explorer 7.

However, mistakenly there one hard coded link, for window.showmodalDialog, which was left with a HTTP link. And I can't change the code in production. The return value is set in the page being called in dialog but it returns `undefined` in the caller page.

Why is it happening like this?

How can I fix this using an HTC file?

Will I get the value if I redirect to the HTTPS URL when the HTTP page is loaded and return the value from there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to deploy a custom HTC file instead of fixing just a single letter in the original code? That's absurd.

Comment: @niutech, modifying single code in original code requires tremendous amounts of approval and headache... Any way I found the solution in the code itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if would be helpful to anyone in future but as still some applications are working on browsers < IE11. So what I did is loaded HTC file on textbox located at the bottom of the page thus causing sufficient delay.